# how to receive a parameter that contains spaces as a single parameter?

Tags: bash

I am making and script with positional parameters the parameters are $1 and $2, the name of the script is script.sh and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
```

and i run it as follows bash script.sh '1 2' 3 in order to consider '1 2' as a single parameter, and i get the following output

```
1 2
3
```

since i am leading with parameters with spaces i want to find a way to obtain the same output without using the quotes inside the code, i would appreciate any suggestion

Comment: You can also escape the space by backslash: `script.sh 1\ 2 3`. But you need to indicate *somehow* that it's not the same as `script.sh 1 2 3` which passes 3 parameters.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. What is your code doing that it shouldn't be? What isn't it doing that it should be? What output are you trying to get instead?

Comment: @EtanReisner He'd get the same output for `script.sh "1        2" 3`, since `echo` would only output one space in place of the whitespace removed by the expansion of `$1`. (And, all the extra whitespace I tried to include between 1 and 2 was stripped by SO.)

Comment: Ah, I see what the question is asking now I think and yes, setting `IFS` can do that but quoting the expansion is the right answer.

Comment: the point is a way to receive a parameter and wait until the user press enter to receive the next positional parameter, i want to find a way to achieve this ....

Answer (score 1):

If you set `IFS` to an empty string, word-splitting will be disabled.

```
$ foo="1       2"
$ IFS=
$ echo $1
1       2
```

However, I can't think of a good reason to do this rather than simply quoting the expansion.